# CakePHP Multiple Model association

Tags: php, cakephp, model, associations

I am confused with the CakePHP 2.x doc [Model Association](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) So need a little help over here to connect and find contains in result.[image]

```
Deal Table > id | title
DealAttribute Table (has options) > id | title
DealAttributeOption Table (belongs to DealAttribute) > id | title | deal_attribute_id
DealsDealAttributes Table > id | deal_id | deal_attribute_id | option_id
```

Need result like

```
Deal [
    id, title
    DealsDealAttributes [
        id, deal_id, deal_attribute_id, option_id
        DealAttribute [
            title
        ]
        DealAttributeOption [
            title
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried with `$belongsTo` and also with `$hasAndBelongsToMany` in `DealsDealAttributes` of all three `Deal, DealAttribute, DealAttributeOption` but didn't get the contains. 
Now i want if i find any Deal then all the associated models will comes in contains. How do i set up the Models association?

Comment: have you defined both $hasMany and $belongsTo relations to respective model ? or are you confusing on doing so ? If u follow cakephp convention on making tables then u can add model relations with cake bake as well..

Comment: It would be helpful to see your existing code for the associations to see what you've tried so far. Basically the model for the table containing a foreign key has a `belongsTo` relationship whereas a model that is associated with another table that contains the foreign key will be a `hasOne` or `hasMany` relationship.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I tried it many ways but no one works thus am confused can you show me the right direction ?

Comment: @Anupal it's a bit confusing from your current question what is needed. Could you maybe include an image of the schema?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Updated question with schema image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model associations should be set up something like this:-

```
class Deal extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = [
        'User'
    ];

    public $hasMany = [
        'DealsDealAttribute'
    ];

}

class DealsDealAttribute extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = [
        'Deal',
        'DealAttribute',
        'DealAttributeOption' => [
            // Foreign key breaks naming convention so needs setting manually
            'foreignKey' => 'option_id'
        ]
    ];

}

class DealAttribute extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = [
        'User'
    ];

    public $hasMany = [
        'DealsDealAttribute'
    ];

}

class DealAttributeOption extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = [
        'DealsDealAttribute'
    ];

}
```

You will need to set the foreign key for the `DealAttributeOption` association in the `DealsDealAttribute` model as you've broken from CakePHP's naming convention (it should ideally be `deal_attribute_option_id`).

**Update**

Then to retrieve a deal with the associated records you can use `contain` to retrieve the relevant models like this:-

```
$result = $this->Deal->find('first', [
    'contain' => [
        'DealsDealAttribute' => [
            'DealAttribute',
            'DealAttributeOption'
        ]
    ],
    'conditions' => [
        'Deal.id' => $id
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I did the same but when i find deal then just `DealsDealAttribute` comes not its associated.

Comment: What are you doing to retrieve the data. It sounds like your find query is wrong!

Comment: `$result = $this->Deal->findById($id);` This is how am finding the deal in controller.

Comment: @Anupal you need to tell Cake what to `contain` in your query. I've updated my answer to show how to do that.